# Large images not centered in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, horizontal-alignment

I'm using the tabular environment to place 2 figures side by side on beamer. When images are "small enough" everything is good, but if I ask for images to be a little larger (using `\textwidth`) the result is that they are not centered horizontally anymore. Here's an example of both not centered and centered:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,multirow,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}


\begin{frame}{Figures are not centered on the sides}{Looks bad :(}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
Some figure 1 & Some figure 2\\
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{These are centered!}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
Some figure 1 & Some figure 2\\
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And it produces:

[image]

I don't know if it's because I'm using `\textwidth`. Maybe I should use something else instead? But I don't know what. Using scale does the same thing.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suppose (I am really sure) that images are not centered by default in beamer. So if you want them to be centered you have to use a center environment or something similar. When your content is too wide for the `\textwidth` it will break out, nevertheless.

Comment: @Jürgen Thanks for the advice but sadly it's not working. I tried adding `\centering` before the tabular environment and it doesn't change anything. Using `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` around tabular changes vertical alignment, but not horizontal. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I tried to tell you: If your content is too wide ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images on your second slide aren't centered, it only looks more or less right due to the values you used. You can put your tabular in a \makebox:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx,multirow,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}


\begin{frame}{Figures are not centered on the slides}{Looks bad :(}

\makebox[\linewidth]{%
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
 Some figure 1 & Some figure 2\\
 \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work when figure environment is used (for capitons, for instance).